# How do I make a layout start on the left side on the screen in access?

Tags: ms-access, layout, ms-access-2010, margins

I'm going to post some pictures to better describe the problem.

This is what I see in layout view:
[image]

And this is what I see in print preview:

[image]

For some reason, it's on the right. But it wasn't before, and I don't know how to make it go back to the left. Is it a margin issue?

Please help!!!

Edit:
Other people having this problem!
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/problem-bug-with-report-margins-automatically/b6fc872b-12aa-464b-aed9-554ecf59bfb5?tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs

Answer (score 0):

How about paper settings...also check the default printer...this two have dramatic effect on reports